# How can I modify the sitemap URL in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

By default, Hugo exposes its site map at `/sitemap.xml`; due to my proxy setup, I need to expose it at `/static-content/sitemap.xml`.

My initial approach was to utilize the capability to [set the sitemap URL front mater](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#set-url-in-front-matter); however, I cannot figure out how create a file in the content directory that will be picked up when rendering the sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the sitemap filename in your Hugo config file. I just tried the following in my config.yaml.

```
sitemap:
  filename: static-content/sitemap.xml
```

And it worked! This is documented in https://gohugo.io/templates/sitemap-template/

Comment: Can't believe this did not occur to me. Thanks!!